# How to undo a resolve in perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am new to this and facing some trouble while checking in my code for the first time.

I have a bunch of opened files in my client. After making my changes, I did a sync to sync my client  to depot. Then I did p4 resolve to resolve the changes. Now, for some files, I had few conflicts. I mistakenly messed up those files and I am not sure how my version is different than the most recent checked-in version in the depot. So, this is what I was trying to do...

1. Sync back to a previous change list, then again do a sync to the HEAD and do p4 resolve- however now it's saying there there is nothing to be resolved.
2. I did a p4 revert to revert my changes, then again modified my files and did sync-> resolve. However again, I'm getting "nothing to be resolved" message.

I am using p4 command line. How can I get back to my old state and resolve the changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you originally made the changes on your local machine and didn't submit them to a branch or shelve them, then you probably wiped out the state of those changes when you ran `p4 revert` (if not before).

If you then synced back to the HEAD and manually redid your changes at that point, then there's genuinely nothing to resolve because you already had the latest revision from the depot before you made your changes.

I would advise checking that your pending changelist has exactly the changes you want and nothing more, either by right-clicking and choosing "Diff against have revision" in p4v, or using `p4 diff` from the command-line. If there's nothing unexpected in there, then submit those changes.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. I have a similar issue. I've made `p4 resolve -ay` but actually meant `-at`, so some of the remote changes did not make it to my local file. If I later `p4 revert -k <file> && p4 edit -c # <file>`, then there is nothing to resolve, while I still don't have the remote changes. I guess the question here is how to get perforce to forget that a `resolve` has been done and get back to to that stage?

Comment: Did you actually check in your changes? If not I'd expect `p4 revert` to forget the resolve completely.

Comment: The files were opened for editing as part of a change but I did not shelve immediately before the checkout. I guess I was looking for something like 'git reflog', where you can undo pulls, merges, etc.